# Lookup for an Entity Column ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, radgridview

I have an Entity Framework Core project that uses generic repositories and UnitOfWork and is working as expected.

The database is one to many and related by IDs.

The `RTCTrials` entity contains a FK `CourseID` related to `RTCCourses` PK. When loading trials I am trying to get the course name in the datagrid and only achieved by using a union. Is this inefficient and a simpler approach. Ideally I would add a dropdownlist column populated with `RTCCourses` in the trials grid template and the `CourseID` in the trials table would select the correct id and show the `ValueMember` course name.

This is what the current method looks like:

```
using (var context = new RTCContext())
{
    var factory = new EntityFrameworkUnitOfWorkFactory(context);
    var unit = factory.Create();

    var festivals = unit.RTCFestivals.All().ToList();
    var trials = unit.RTCTrials.All().ToList();
    var courses = unit.RTCCourses.All().ToList();

    var trialcourses = trials.Join(courses, courses => courses.CourseID, trials => trials.CourseID, (trials, courses) => new
            {
                TrialID = trials.TrialID,
                FestivalID = trials.FestivalID,
                CourseID = trials.CourseID,
                Trial = trials.Trial,
                Course = courses.CourseName,
                TrialGrade = trials.TrialGrade,
                TrialDistance = trials.TrialDistance,
                TrialAge = trials.TrialAge,
                TrialHurdles = trials.TrialHurdles,
                TrialAllowances = trials.TrialAllowances,
                TrialMonth = trials.TrialMonth,
                TrialActualDate = trials.TrialActualDate,
                TrialActualTime = trials.TrialActualTime,
                TrialRaceCard = trials.TrialRaceCard,
                TrialQualifiers = trials.TrialQualifiers
            }).ToList();

    this.radGridViewFestivalDestinations.DataSource = festivals;
    this.radGridViewFestivalDestinations.Templates[0].DataSource = trialcourses;

    foreach (GridViewDataColumn column in radGridViewFestivalDestinations.MasterTemplate.Columns)
    {
        column.BestFit();
    }

    foreach (GridViewDataColumn column in radGridViewFestivalDestinations.Templates[0].Columns)
    {
        column.BestFit();
    }
}
```

[image: Entity Diagram]

RTCTrial Entity

```
public partial class RTCTrial {

    public RTCTrial()
    {
        this.RTCResults = new List<RTCResult>();
        this.RTCWeathers = new List<RTCWeather>();
        OnCreated();
    }

    public virtual int TrialID { get; set; }

    public virtual int FestivalID { get; set; }

    public virtual int CourseID { get; set; }

    public virtual string Trial { get; set; }

    public virtual string TrialGrade { get; set; }

    public virtual string TrialDistance { get; set; }

    public virtual string TrialAge { get; set; }

    public virtual int? TrialHurdles { get; set; }

    public virtual string TrialAllowances { get; set; }

    public virtual string TrialMonth { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? TrialActualDate { get; set; }

    public virtual TimeSpan? TrialActualTime { get; set; }

    public virtual string TrialRaceCard { get; set; }

    public virtual int TrialQualifiers { get; set; }

    public virtual RTCCourse RTCCourse { get; set; }

    public virtual RTCFestival RTCFestival { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<RTCResult> RTCResults { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<RTCWeather> RTCWeathers { get; set; }

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions

    partial void OnCreated();

    #endregion
}
```

RTCCourse Entity

```
public partial class RTCCourse {

    public RTCCourse()
    {
        this.RTCTrials = new List<RTCTrial>();
        OnCreated();
    }

    public virtual int CourseID { get; set; }

    public virtual string CourseName { get; set; }

    public virtual string CourseCountry { get; set; }

    public virtual string CourseDirection { get; set; }

    public virtual string CourseCharacteristics { get; set; }

    public virtual string CourseAlternateName { get; set; }

    public virtual double CourseLat { get; set; }

    public virtual double CourseLong { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<RTCTrial> RTCTrials { get; set; }

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions

    partial void OnCreated();

    #endregion
}
```

Regards, Neil

Comment: From what you show -- it seems you have a row for each course (trialcourses) - but you want a row for each trial and a dropdown with the courses for the trial.   I would have the returned `trails` contain the courses.  Have that unit of work `Include(t -> t.Courses)` -- that's assuming you have a List<RTCCourse> defined in your RTCTrial and relationship set up in your context.  That would also mean you would not be binding to your anonymous object any more... quite a bit of refactoring, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I have update to show the two entities, the trials does not have an IList, it's declared, public virtual RTCCourse RTCCourse { get; set; }.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion would be on the returned `courses` you would want each course to have its associated trials.  In the unit of work that returns all courses - possibly have an option to include them.  Your dropdown would bind to each course and your grid would bind to the list of trials in the selected course.

```cs
    public IEnumerable<RTCCourse> All(bool includeTrials = false)
    {
        var q = context.RTCCourses;
        if (includeTrials)
        {
            q = q.Include(c => c.RTCTrials)//.ThenInclude(t => t.RTCResults)
            ;
        }
        return q.AsEnumerable(); // assuming that is the returned type
    }
```

That should allow your `courses` to have the list of trials set.  Then there is no need to get all `trials`.  And you can bind to courses (and list of trials within each) directly instead of doing the join and binding to the anonymous.

Of 'course' -- this is merely a suggestion ;)